# Wrong detection of Circle when using cv2.minEnclosingCircle

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect and draw a circle in somes grayscale images using OpenCV. The Canny Edge Detection works perfectly, but for some reason the circle derived the points in the Canny fit horribly. I accept any suggestions for detecting the circle or that might sole

Here is the code I used(sorry for the weird variable names in portuguese)

```
masc_limbo = cv2.imread(path_masc_limbo)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi_masc, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray , 100, 200)
cv2_imshow(canny)

points = np.argwhere(canny > 0)
center, raio = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(points)
center= (int(center[0]), int(center[1]) )
raio = int(raio)
cv2.circle(roi_masc, center, 1, (255, 200, 0), 3)
cv2.circle(roi_masc, center, raio, (255, 0, 255), 2)
cv2_imshow(roi_masc)
```

Canny result:

[image: Canny result:]

Enclosing Circles result:

[image: Enclosing Circles result:]

Comment: Your contour has the X and Y components swapped (due to generating it with `np.argwhere` -- numpy is row-major by default).

Comment: Replace `points = np.argwhere(canny > 0)` with 
`points = np.argwhere(canny.transpose()>0)`